# How to save data of GridView through javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net

I am developer in .NET and i have joined the company last few months before so please help me about this questions because i am facing problem in it...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)Create a comma(,) separated or pipe(|) separated string(which contains row by row grid values) client side by looping through GridView.

```
EX: Row1Column1Value~Row1Column2Value~Row1Column3Value|Row2Column1Value~
Row2Column2Value~Row2Column3Value~
```

Step 2)Create Ajax function function in code behind ex: UpdateDateTable(string gridValue)

Step 3)Create datatable using gridValue

Step 4)Now you have datatable and u can save values in database.